# I can't understand this? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm new to RoR and I am having some trouble understanding some of the code.
I tried looking it up but the results haven't helped me.

Here is the code located in the user controller. (If you need any other code, comment it and I'll update

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
   @user = User.new(user_params) #I didn't see any parameters in the constructor
    if @user.save #Checks if @user was saved?
     session[:user_id] = @user.id #Creates a session? What's :user_id and @user_id?
     redirect_to'/' #Redirects to http://localhost:8000/
    else
     redirect_to '/signup' #If all fails go back to signup page
   end
end

private
def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
 end 
end
```

This is part of a programming course which failed to explain this to me properly. I'm generally aware that this is for a signup form, but I am having trouble comprehending the create and user_params function processes.

When I'm asking for help I am asking you to lead me through the process of what is happening.
I also need specific help with 
`params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@user = User.new(user_params) #I didn't see any parameters in the constructor
```

`user_params` is the name of a method.  In ruby, you can call a method without writing `()` after the method name.  If you look down at the bottom of the code you posted, you can see the method definition:

```
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
  end 
end
```

That method returns something, and that return value is used in the constructor.   You can see what the return value is by adding the following to your code:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  puts '******'
  p user_params
  puts '******'
  ...
  ...
end
```

Then look in your server window for the output. You'll see something like:

```
****** 
{“first_name"=>”Joe”, “last_name”=>”Smith”, “email”=>”joe_smith@yahoo.com”}
*******
```

`params.require` has to do with security.  The subject is called `strong parameters`, which you can read about here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/

```
if @user.save #Checks if @user was saved?
```

Yes:

> By default, `save` always run validations. If any of them fail the
>   action is cancelled and save returns false.

```
session[:user_id] = @user.id #Creates a session? What's :user_id and @user_id?
```

A session is used to make variables persist from one request to another. A session is like a Hash, and `:user_id` is just a random key that you are creating in the Hash.   You can name the key anything you want, but it should describe the data that you are saving.

`@user.id` is the value you are saving in the session Hash.  The `id` comes from the user you created here:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

> I'm generally aware that this is for a signup form, but I am having
>   trouble comprehending the create and user_params function processes.

First, you use a GET request to display the form for creating a new user--you do that by entering `localhost:3000/users/new` in your browser.  That will display the form.  The `<form>` tag has an `action` attribute, which specifies the url where the form will send a request accompanied by the data.

If you use your browser's developer tools, you can click on something like `Page Source` to see the raw html of the form, which will look something like this:

```
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
...
...
```

A POST request that is sent to the url `/users` is routed to the `create` action in the UsersController.  That's because when you declare a route like:

```
resources :users
```

or

```
resources :photos
```

Rails uses [the chart below](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to route urls to actions (in this case the urls are routed to actions in the PhotosController):

[image]

Note that the url `/photos` is routed to both the `index` and the `create` action.  Rails checks whether the request is a GET request or a POST request to determine which action to execute.

For additional information, check out the [Rails Guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two thins going on here. The controller is probably mapped to `/users/` path. The controller will direct all `POST` to `create`. Similarly, it will direct all `GET` to `index`. Which you don't have.

`user_params` is a function that was created probably as part of your scaffolding. Like `rails generate ...` In older versions of Rails, it wasn't like this. This allows you to say for the user scope, first_name, last_name, etc are allowed to be submitted via POST. Why is this done? Mostly security. It allows you to whitelisted parameters so that for example `user.admin` cannot be updated. You can read more about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Comment: Actually all of this was written manually as instructions. Specifically in the user_params class, I don't understand where the :user symbol came from.
My assumption is that :user is the table in the User module and the first_name, last_name etc are the fields.

Comment: That's right. `:user` maps to the `User` class, which maps to `users` table. This is why they call RoR convention over configuration. You wouldn't know about this, because there are no config files saying what :user is. You would just have to know User class requires fields all in `"user"` scope when POSTing in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In your web-app you may want to create and update users' information.
For example, in both your views new.html.erb ( which create new user) and edit.html.erb (which update existing user's information), you will probably render a form to let users type their information (with bootstrap).

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-xs-12'>

    <%= form_for(@user, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role:"form"}) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                <%= f.label :first_name,"FName:" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter username", autofocus: true %>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                <%= f.label :last_name,"LName:" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter username" %>
            </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">            
                <%= f.label :email, "Email:" %>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter your email" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">            
                <%= f.label :password, "Password:" %>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter your password" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <%= f.submit(@user.new_record? ? "Sign up now!" : "Update your account", class:'btn btn-primary btn-lg') %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        [ <%= link_to 'Cancel request and return to home', root_path %> ]
    </div>

</div>
```

Back to your question:
By doing "params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)" will allow the user controller to modify you first_name, last_name, email and password parameter with security.

Comment: But in the User module there is no parameter "password", only ":password_digest".